# Application Insghts Failed request Error 405

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, appinsights

Hi when I deploy my site to Azure I see in App Insights a lot of "Failed request count" with status code result 405 for a page where I do not have any POST action.

If I see in my local App Insights I do not receive that alert.
I am new with app insights and Azure, so I am not sure how to check what is the cause of this
I checked the logs but nothing relevant is displayed.

I am using MVC Core 3.1
[image: Appinsights]

Answer (score 0):

I got my issue solved.
I realized that I had a service pointing to that URL.